# What are the differences between the PS3 and 360 versions of Crysis 2?

Tags: crysis-2

I am looking to buy Crysis 2, but am trying to figure out which system to buy it on.  I don't have a fast enough computer (yet), so my choice is between the PS3 and Xbox360.  I am looking for an overall judgement since no one factor will probably make up my mind (buying for one system based on graphics alone). Can someone break down any differences between the graphics, single-player, multi-player, known issues, etc.?

Comment: Game recommendations are offtopic here.  Please check out the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: You might find this useful: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16639/does-a-website-exist-that-compares-the-versions-of-the-same-game-on-different-pla

Comment: I edited the question so that it's asking for what the differences are between the versions of the game, similar to a Rock Band question I think we had floating around on the site. It'll really be up to the OP to decide which to buy based on the comparison made.

Comment: You can only play multiplayer on the Xbox version. At least for the last 6 days. :) Sorry PSN, had to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the developers](http://www.develop-online.net/news/32077/No-clear-difference-between-360-and-PS3-versions-of-Crysis-2-says-Crytek) there shouldn't be any differences. In any case, [here's a video comparison of actual gameplay](http://www.eurogamer.net/videos/crysis-2-pc-360-ps3-face-off-comparison) between the 2 platforms (and the PC).

Answer (score 1):

There should be no differences. Crytek even dares players to find differences. See http://nexus404.com/Blog/2011/03/17/crytek-challenges-players-to-find-360ps3-crysis-2-differences-crytek-responds-to-claims-that-ps3-version-of-crysis-2-is-inferior-to-360-version-by-challenging-players-to-find-a-meaningful-differen/